# Could anyone tell something about using ::Ptr and new operator when using PCL

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I tried to declare an object of a PCL class with

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointNT> PointCloudT;   // in the .h file.
```

and

```
PointCloudT::Ptr object = new PointCloudT();   // in main func
PointCloudT::Ptr scene = new PointCloudT();    // and these two triggers the error of
```

1>f:\cpps\pclrclass\pclrclass\main_routine.cpp(10): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'PointCloudT *' to 'boost::shared_ptr>'

but it works if the declaration is given by

```
PointCloudT::Ptr object(new PointCloudT);   // in main func
PointCloudT::Ptr scene(new PointCloudT);    // works and correct
```

I am not good at C++ and don't know what the problem is of this error. Could anyone tell a little about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new PointCloudT()` expression yields a raw pointer to a point cloud, `PointCloudT *`.

`PointCloudT::Ptr` is a synonym for `boost::shared_ptr<PointCloudT>`, a smart pointer to a point cloud. You can look up the synopsis of this template class [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). As you can see, it has a constructor

```
  template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y * p);
```

which in our case becomes

```
  explicit shared_ptr(PointCloudT * p);
```

This means that it can be constructed from a raw pointer to a point cloud. Note the [`explicit` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), which forbids implicit construction and copy-initialization.

This is why the first snippet gives error (you request implicit conversion between two different classes), and the second snippet works (you explicitly call the constructor of shared pointer).